# IE 8 - script to update browser configuration

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, scripting

For the deployment of a specific Web application on IE (from 6 to 8, but let's concentrate on the 8), I need to set some specific security settings.

There are a lot of them and some are touchy (well, not that much but all my users don't talk computer fluently :-) ), so I'm looking for a kind of batch (an .exe, a .bat, a .reg possibly if these parameters can only be set in the Register DB, the best being a .NET app) to set them via a single double-click before the deployment.

Thanks for your help and ideas !

Comment: Can you set this up through group policies?

Comment: Well, I'm opened to all proposals :-) How exactly do group policies work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally ended up in a `.reg` file that modifies registry entries...
Just to let you know:

- if you want to add a site to a zone, add folders to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains`
- if you want to change a security setting for a zone, change it in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones` (a good description of the zones is in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms908714.aspx))